# How can I make a Stylebot style only apply to the home page of a site?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, css

When I create a new style for a given page, like here:
[image: Stylebot Options]

How can I make the style apply **only** to the home page of that site?

- `http://superuser.com` **should** be affected.
- `http://superuser.com/questions` **shouldn't** be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

You can't right now.

### Long answer

Stylebot support 2 methods of matching a style against a given URL.

- Simple substring matching
- Something that looks like a pattern matching approach

You can get into the second mode by putting a `*` anywhere in the URL. But the only option that this enables you, is to use the placeholder `*`. The star means *any amount of any character* and is as useless as the night is dark.

This is especially mind-boggling because the extension is perfectly equipped to use the pattern as a regular expression, but [**intentionally doesn't**](https://github.com/ankit/stylebot/blob/master/stylebot/js/background.js#L982).

Feel free to use [my own fork](https://github.com/oliversalzburg/stylebot) that removes this limitation.

Comment: Would you be able to update this fork so that it works with the current version of Chrome?

Comment: @JoelChristophel I think the official version has proper support now. Either way, I couldn't update the fork.

Comment: Do you know the syntax for the current version? Their website has been down for quite some time. I want for a style to only be applied on the root domain.